# Jquery mouseover & mouseout animation bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a small mouseover and  mouseout functionality i have to keep the mouseout function animate() instead of css() due to other reasons

the problem arises when i mouseover when the animation from opacity 1 to 0 is still going on like a quick mouseover mouseout like we do for testing.

i tried setTimeOut too so that the opacity is zeroed after required time.

both animate and setTimeOut are creating the same problem that after mouserover function updates the opacity to 1 the animate and setTimeOut are updating again to zero since they are still playing.
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/avi_sagi/5Ekbf/2/)
Jquery Code:

```
$("#dp-ashish").on("mouseover",function(){
    $("#dp-ashish").css("opacity","1");
});
$("#dp-ashish").on("mouseout",function(){
    $("#dp-ashish").animate({"opacity":"0"},1000);          
});
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the issue. Could you possibly recreate the issue in a Jsfiddle?

Comment: i added the jsfiddle @JosephDailey

Comment: @RobSedgwick its works the same way
its not preventing the play of animate when i mouseover

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using either `.stop(true, true)` or `.finish()` (the latter only works in jQuery v1.9 and above):

```
$("#dp-ashish").on("mouseover",function(){
    $("#dp-ashish").stop(true,true).animate({opacity:1},1000);
});
$("#dp-ashish").on("mouseout",function(){
    $("#dp-ashish").stop(true,true).animate({opacity:0},1000);          
});
```

or:

```
$("#dp-ashish").on("mouseover",function(){
    $("#dp-ashish").finish().animate({opacity:1},1000);
});
$("#dp-ashish").on("mouseout",function(){
    $("#dp-ashish").finish().animate({opacity:0},1000);          
});
```

p/s: The `opacity` and its numerical integer value do not need to be wrapped in quotes. Opacity is a valid property without needing to be parsed as a string, and its accepted values are integers which do not need to be passed as a string, too.

**Alternatively, you can toggle a CSS class** and let CSS transitions handle the opacity change :)

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/5Ekbf/4/

Comment: your jsfiddle itself not working
sometimes the person is getting blurred due to the animate()
if u are not experiencing it and u feel u are right il check on another computer

Comment: If that is the case, you should use `.animate()` when changing the opacity to 1. A better recommendation is to simply toggle on and off a class, and use CSS transitions to achieve opacity transitions. Browser's rendering engines have its own way of preventing transition queues from stacking up.